# Breakpoint when encountering RunTimeWarning

Tags: python, numpy, breakpoints

I am having trouble getting the following code to work in Python:

```
for t in range(-5,5):
    try:
        a = np.log(t)
    except RunTimeWarning:
        breakpoint()
```

What I want is to execute the breakpoint statement, when the log function is evaluated from -5 to 0.

Comment: This says to execute `breakpoint` when `np.log` *fails*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `np.log(0)`, numpy won't throw an exception but a *warning*. These are significantly different from exceptions as an exception will stop the current code from running, whereas a warning just notifies you but keeps the code running.

Take this example:

```
>>> x = np.log(0)

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
>>> x
-inf
```

As you can see the variable x does get a value assigned -> the warning never kept `log(...)` from running and returning a value.

So to solve your problem, you'd have to check if the value passed to your code is 0 before calling `np.log`. Or if you don't want -inf to be a valid return value but still need to call `np.log` for some reason, you can check if the value is -inf after the call. However it's best practise not to write code that causes warnings so you should probably just check if it's 0 before calling log.

You can read more about warnings in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html).